# i want to fetch the last row by default mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I am doing mysql queries but I got a problem for fetching the last row. guys, do you know is there any built in mysql query to find out the last low from a table. now , i am using these query but i think this is lengthy-

```
select latitude,longitude,speed 
from trackerEngine 
order by timeUpdated desc
```

Comment: `ORDER BY timeUpdated ASC LIMIT 1`? Or DESC depending on whether that SQL is your attempt at getting the last row, or you're asking to get the last row of this query since "last" is relative to your ordering.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `LIMIT`?

```
select latitude,longitude,speed 
from trackerEngine 
order by timeUpdated desc
limit 1
```

This will though find last row from a table ordered by `timeUpdated`, which with `DESC` means the highest value existing in this column.

Note, that `NULL` values are higher than non-null ones.

Comment: LIMIT 1, I already used. but is there any query like LAST UPDATE ROW or something similar build in MYSQL function ?

Comment: Well, you did not mention using limit clause. There is a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, but you may also like to look at the updated timestamp.

Comment: can you give me any example about updated timestamp query ?